# Android needing to send Intent when going back

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

[image: Sketch]

this is my basic Sketch from the App I wrote, my Problem is that I Navigate between my Activities with (black arrows)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, someclass.class);
intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
startActivity(intent);
```

I am not using `finish()` to go back since I dont know wether it recreates my previous Activity, or if it just goes back without recreating. The main Problem here is that i need to pass pos around while i really only use it in `FlashCardActivity` but when I go back from, for example `FlashcardChangeActivity` it gets recreated which is good, since I want my elements of my RecyclerView to be actualized. I need the pos there since I call a Function in my Database which returns all the elements of a certain Folder which I will display than.

So how do I implement this more clean and better without having to drag around the pos.

(I would also have a UML Classdiagramm and my Code but i think the Picture i drew shows my Problem better)

Comment: Have you tried [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)?

Comment: but wouldn't i have to send "pos" with the intent and as the result back?